# Can Map hold the java class ByteArrayoutputstream as values? Can List hold the javax.mail.MimeMessage objects?

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist, memory-management, jakarta-mail

I am using JavaMail API to send emails in my java web application. My use case is to send multiple emails to different recipients with the user-specific content. the content includes the pdf file attachment. I want to do code as follows,

```
Map<Long, ByteArrayOutputStream> pdffiles = new HashMap<Long, ByteArrayOutputStream>();
Map<Long, String> contentMap = new HashMap<Long,String>();
start of loop
{
   String userId = //uniqId;
   ByteArrayOutputStream outFile= new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   outFile  = // statement to invoke a method to create the customer 
    specific pdf file 
   String fileName = "Invoice_<company_name>"+".pdf";   
   MimeBodyPart pdfBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
   pdffiles.put(userId, outFile);
   String content   = //Some user specific content loaded here.
   contentMap.put(userId, content);

}

Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
@Override
protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
}
});

List<MimeMessage> msgList= new ArrayList<MimeMessage>();
for(Long userid : contentMap.keySet()){
   String content = contentMap.get();
   String contentType  ="text/html;charset=UTF-8";
   MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
   ByteArrayOutputStream outFile = // get the pdf file from map using the userid as key 
   byte[] bytes = outFile.toByteArray();
   DataSource dataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(bytes, 
                                             "application/pdf");
   pdfBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(dataSource));

   Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
   try {
         //adding the passed multipart content to the mail that to send 
      as an inline attachment.
       messageBodyPart.setContent(content, contentType);
       multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
       multipart.addBodyPart(pdfBodyPart);
       msg.setContent(multipart);
       // have to add this 'msg' Object in List.

       InternetAddress[] addressTo = null;
       try {
         addressTo = InternetAddress.parse(eo.getTo());
         msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);
        } catch (AddressException e) {
         // excpetion handled here
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
         // excpetion handled here
        }
   }catch (MessagingException e) {
   } catch (Exception e) {//expetion handled here
  }
}

Transport transport = null;
try {
    transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
} catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
  //exception handled here
}

try {
  transport.connect();
  for(MimeMessage msg : msgList){
     transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
  }
  transport.close();
}catch (Exception ex) {
   //exception handled here
}
```

My question is,
Does HashMap accept the ByteArrayOutputStream class instance as values? if so how to get it from Map by using the key?

Does ArrayList accept to hold the MimeMessage Object? if so,
What if the MimeMessage has large files in its Bodyparts? what will happen when holding large files in memory as List?

Comment: If your attachments are all files, there is no reason to store their contents in ByteArrayOutputStreams or byte arrays.  You can [attach a File directly](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#attachFile-java.io.File-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), and save your Java process a lot of memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `HashMap` and `ArrayList` can store any subtype of `Object`, including `ByteArrayOutputStream` or `MimeMessage` as values.

Perhaps answering part of your confusion: These data structures do not store the actual objects "inside" themselves; rather `HashMap` and `ArrayList` store *references* to objects that must already exist in memory.

So as long as you have enough memory to *create* the `ByteArrayOutputStream`, the extra memory to store a reference to it is unlikely to be a problem.

Comment: It might be better to store the actual byte array itself, rather than the ByteArrayOutputStream.

Comment: In most cases, I would agree. The main reason why you'd want a Map containing BAOS instances is if you're writing to all of them concurrently or something. In any case, the point of this answer is that you can put any kind of Object you like as a value in a Map since the object itself isn't "inside" the Map but just referenced from it.